# Why is the Find function returning "#Value" when the statement returns False?

Tags: excel, if-statement, find

I am trying to write a find function, and the [value_if_true] is given "Yes" and [value_if_false] is given "No". Here's the simple code:

```
=IF(FIND("T",B2),"Yes","No",)
```

Cell B2 contians "Apples" If I put "A" into the first part of the "FIND" function, the function returns "YES", as it should. But when I put "T" or anything that is not in the word "Apples", it returns #VALUE. I do not know why. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: find returns the position of the substring if it doesnt find it it returns value error. (http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/find.php)

Answer (score 2):

Archaic question but because it is recurring, I will post the most common solution. You just need to use ISERROR function alongside IF and FIND, because FIND tries to find the value and if it doesn't find it then correctly it returns error, so we need to handle the error as part of the IF statement. Hence for example, if we need to check wether a string contains "-" or not, use the following:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("-";A2);0);TRUE;FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is determined by the specification of the FIND function. When there is nothing found it returns the #VALUE error. You might want to have a look at [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/find.php) as a reference.